# Access Timer Interrupts in Raspian

Tags: wiringpi, real-time, interrupts

I want to write a C program that runs some code at a fixed interval (somewhere between 200us and 1ms, TBD).  Is it possible to use the hardware timer interrupts to execute code without resorting to writing a kernel driver?  I'm hesitant to use any delay functions since that doesn't always ensure that the code fires off at a fixed interval.  (The period is the delay PLUS the time it takes to execute the rest of the code, which may vary).

I saw that the WiringPi library allows you to attach code to a GPIO interrupt, but I didn't see anything about a timer.  I would ideally like to do something similar with a timer interrupt.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/63429/19949) provides some results that might be relevant to your endeavour - while it addresses GPIO events, the same underlying mechanisms will be important for timer interrupts.